# How to use multiple variables in phpMyAdmin bookmarked SQL queries?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have tried the last unreleased version of phpMyAdmin (4.5.0) to try out the multi-variables in bookmarked SQL queries. I had a bookmarked query that was something like :

```
SELECT COUNT(\*) FROM table1 /* WHERE column1 > [VARIABLE1] AND column2 > [VARIABLE2] */
```

But no input field were shown when I selected my query from the dropdown bookmarked menu.
Issue #933 from GitHub tells that it is closed, is it ready or I did something wrong?

Comment: given that the variables are commented out, they're not really variables... just some random characters inside a comment.

Comment: Can you please link to the issue?

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/feature-requests/933/

Comment: And the documentation is already updated... http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html#bookmarks-where-can-i-store-bookmarks-why-can-t-i-see-any-bookmarks-below-the-query-box-what-are-these-variables-for

Comment: @MarcB If I refer to the documentation, this is the way to do it, isn't it? In 4.4.9, when I put in comment /* WHERE column1 > [VARIABLE] */ it works. Even that bookmarked query, in 4.5.0 don't allow me to put some value into my variable (input box don't show).

Comment: @PhilippeArnold: that should indeed work http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/bookmarks.html#bookmarks